# Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 android studio

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

I am getting this error while i run program in the Android studio.. There is no anyother is here i guess.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:createDebugMainDexClassList'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Here it is my gradle file copy..

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.example.com"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    lintOptions { abortOnError false }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/socialauth-4.9.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5')
            {
              exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
            }
}
```

what's the issue ?

Comment: which line ?? @JaydeepPatel

Comment: remove the compileOptions version.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel not working.

Answer (score 1):

its seems to be multidex issue. just add maximum heap size and multidex library dependency.

android {

```
dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
}
```

}

defaultConfig {

```
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

also put Dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

you will also need to extend your application class to MultiDexApplication

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    // Initialize 
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
{
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

}

Don't forgot to make an entry of app class in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in app build.gradle worked for me

```
defaultConfig {
// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}
```